# Trying to parse an xml file into an Object in C# aspx.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a problem trying to serialize an XML file into an object.
I got this to work in an other project, but this time it does not work.
The object and its elements are always empty.

My XML file:

```
  <ConferenceTextAttributes>
  <_lbl_TitleOfPage_Text>Registration</_lbl_TitleOfPage_Text>
  <_lbl_textBoxInfo_Text>(* mandatory fields)</_lbl_textBoxInfo_Text>
  <_lbl_mrsmr_Text>Mr/Ms:*</_lbl_mrsmr_Text>
  <_txt_mrsmr_Text></_txt_mrsmr_Text>
  <_lbl_title_Text>Title:</_lbl_title_Text>
  <_txt_title_Text></_txt_title_Text>
  <_lbl_firstname_Text>First Name:*</_lbl_firstname_Text>
  <_txt_firstname_Text></_txt_firstname_Text>
  <_lbl_surname_Text>Surname:*</_lbl_surname_Text>
  <_txt_surname_Text></_txt_surname_Text>
  <_lbl_institution_Text>Institution:*</_lbl_institution_Text>
  <_txt_institution_Text></_txt_institution_Text>
  <_lbl_department_Text>Department:*</_lbl_department_Text>
  <_txt_department_text></_txt_department_text>
  <_lbl_address_Text>Address:*</_lbl_address_Text>
  <_txt_address_text></_txt_address_text>
  <_lbl_zip_Text>Zip Code:*</_lbl_zip_Text>
  <_txt_zip_Text></_txt_zip_Text>
  <_lbl_city_Text>City:*</_lbl_city_Text>
  <_txt_city_Text></_txt_city_Text>
  <_lbl_country_Text>Country:*</_lbl_country_Text>
  <_txt_country_Text></_txt_country_Text>
  <_lbl_phone_Text>Phone:*</_lbl_phone_Text>
  <_txt_phone_Text></_txt_phone_Text>
  <_lbl_fax_Text>Fax:</_lbl_fax_Text>
  <_txt_fax_Text></_txt_fax_Text>
  <_lbl_email_Text>E-mail:*</_lbl_email_Text>
  <_txt_email_Text></_txt_email_Text>
  <_lbl_info_Text>I participate as a (former) mebmer of:</_lbl_info_Text>
  <_lbl_dropdown1_Text>If you are (former) member of NGFN-Plus / NGFN-Transfer please select</_lbl_dropdown1_Text>
  <_lbl_other_Text>other:</_lbl_other_Text>
  <_txt_other_Text></_txt_other_Text>
  <_lbl_chbInfo_Text>I will participate on these days:</_lbl_chbInfo_Text>
  <_chkb_day01_text>Montag</_chkb_day01_text>
  <_chkb_day02_text>Dienstag</_chkb_day02_text>
  <_chkb_day03_text>Mittwoch</_chkb_day03_text>
  <_chkb_day04_text>Donnerstag</_chkb_day04_text>
  <_chkb_day05_text>Freitag</_chkb_day05_text>
  <_chkb_day06_text>Samstag</_chkb_day06_text>
  <_chkb_day07_text>Sonntag</_chkb_day07_text>
  <_b_submit_Text>Register!</_b_submit_Text>
  <_b_cancle_Text>Cancel!</_b_cancle_Text>
  </ConferenceTextAttributes>
```

My class:

```
public class ConferenceTextAttributes
{
    //Registration
    public string lbl_TitleOfPage_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_textBoxInfo_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_mrsmr_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_mrsmr_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_title_text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_title_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_firstname_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_firstname_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_surname_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_surname_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_institution_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_institution_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_department_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_department_text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_address_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_address_text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_zip_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_zip_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_city_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_city_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_country_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_country_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_phone_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_phone_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_fax_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_fax_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_email_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_email_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_info_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_dropdown1_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_other_Text = string.Empty;
    public string txt_other_Text = string.Empty;
    public string lbl_chbInfo_Text = string.Empty;
    public string chkb_day01_text = string.Empty;
    public string chkb_day02_text = string.Empty;
    public string chkb_day03_text = string.Empty;
    public string chkb_day04_text = string.Empty;
    public string chkb_day05_text = string.Empty;
    public string chkb_day06_text = string.Empty;
    public string chkb_day07_text = string.Empty;
    public string b_submit_Text = string.Empty;
    public string b_cancle_Text = string.Empty;

    public ConferenceTextAttributes(string _lbl_TitleOfPage_Text,string _lbl_textBoxInfo_Text, string _lbl_mrsmr_Text, string _txt_mrsmr_Text, string _lbl_title_text, string _txt_title_Text, string _lbl_firstname_Text, string _txt_firstname_Text, string _lbl_surname_Text, string _txt_surname_Text, string _lbl_institution_Text, string _txt_institution_Text, string _lbl_department_Text, string _txt_department_text, string _lbl_address_Text, string _txt_address_text, string _lbl_zip_Text, string _txt_zip_Text, string _lbl_city_Text, string _txt_city_Text, string _lbl_country_Text, string _txt_country_Text, string _lbl_phone_Text, string _txt_phone_Text, string _lbl_fax_Text, string _txt_fax_Text, string _lbl_email_Text, string _txt_email_Text, string _lbl_info_Text, string _lbl_dropdown1_Text, string _lbl_other_Text, string _txt_other_Text, string _lbl_chbInfo_Text, string _chkb_day01_text, string _chkb_day02_text, string _chkb_day03_text, string _chkb_day04_text, string _chkb_day05_text, string _chkb_day06_text, string _chkb_day07_text, string _b_submit_Text, string _b_cancle_Text)
    {
        lbl_TitleOfPage_Text = _lbl_TitleOfPage_Text;
        lbl_textBoxInfo_Text = _lbl_textBoxInfo_Text;
        lbl_mrsmr_Text = _lbl_mrsmr_Text;
        txt_mrsmr_Text = _txt_mrsmr_Text;
        lbl_title_text = _lbl_title_text;
        txt_title_Text = _txt_title_Text;
        lbl_firstname_Text = _lbl_firstname_Text;
        txt_firstname_Text = _txt_firstname_Text;
        lbl_surname_Text = _lbl_surname_Text;
        txt_surname_Text = _txt_surname_Text;
        lbl_institution_Text = _lbl_institution_Text;
        txt_institution_Text = _txt_institution_Text;
        lbl_department_Text = _lbl_department_Text;
        txt_department_text = _txt_department_text;
        lbl_address_Text = _lbl_address_Text;
        txt_address_text = _txt_address_text;
        lbl_zip_Text = _lbl_zip_Text;
        txt_zip_Text = _txt_zip_Text;
        lbl_city_Text = _lbl_city_Text;
        txt_city_Text = _txt_city_Text;
        lbl_country_Text = _lbl_country_Text;
        txt_country_Text = _txt_country_Text;
        lbl_phone_Text = _lbl_phone_Text;
        txt_phone_Text = _txt_phone_Text;
        lbl_fax_Text = _lbl_fax_Text;
        txt_fax_Text = _txt_fax_Text;
        lbl_email_Text = _lbl_email_Text;
        txt_email_Text = _txt_email_Text;
        lbl_info_Text = _lbl_info_Text;
        lbl_dropdown1_Text = _lbl_dropdown1_Text;
        lbl_other_Text = _lbl_other_Text;
        txt_other_Text = _txt_other_Text;
        lbl_chbInfo_Text = _lbl_chbInfo_Text;
        chkb_day01_text = _chkb_day01_text;
        chkb_day02_text = _chkb_day02_text;
        chkb_day03_text = _chkb_day03_text;
        chkb_day04_text = _chkb_day04_text;
        chkb_day05_text = _chkb_day05_text;
        chkb_day06_text = _chkb_day06_text;
        chkb_day07_text = _chkb_day07_text;
        b_submit_Text = _b_submit_Text;
        b_cancle_Text = _b_cancle_Text;
    }

     public ConferenceTextAttributes()
     {

     }
}
```

My method to serialize:

```
public ConferenceTextAttributes LeseMeistenTextAttribute(string sPfad2)
{
    XmlSerializer ser2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConferenceTextAttributes));
    StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(sPfad2);
    ConferenceTextAttributes MyTextAttributes = 
        (ConferenceTextAttributes)ser2.Deserialize(sr2);
    sr2.Close();
    return MyTextAttributes;
}
```

Comment: tag name: `_lbl_TitleOfPage_Text` field name: `lbl_TitleOfPage_Text` spot the difference.

Comment: Okay i deleted all the underscores now it works!
Thanks!!
What i cant understand, i did it like the first time in the other project, there are also underscores in the xml file, and even the classes are the same. and the it works...
Anyway, what took me 4h to find took u 2 seconds, Thanks my Master!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are extra underscores in the field names in the xml. Use XmlElement attributes in you class to specify those.

```
[XmlElement("_lbl_msmr_text")]
public string lbl_msmr_text { get; set; }
```

Comment: i´m not shure if i got what u mean.
Did u mean That: </_lbl_mrsmr_Text>?

Comment: Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2baksw0z(v=vs.100).aspx